# Python socket library: OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.

I am getting the above error..My server and client can send and receive their first messages but I get this error if I try to send more than one message.

My Server Code is here

```
import socket
import threading
import time
from tkinter import *


#functions
def t_recv():
    r = threading.Thread(target=recv)
    r.start()

def recv():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as listensocket:
        port = 5354
        maxconnections = 9
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        print(ip)
        server = (ip, port)
        FORMAT = 'utf-8'

        listensocket.bind((server))
        listensocket.listen(maxconnections)
        (clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()
        msg = f'\[ALERT\] {address} has joined the chat.'
        lstbox.insert(0, msg)

    while True:
        sendermessage = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
        if not sendermessage == "":
            time.sleep(3)
            lstbox.insert(0, 'Client: ' +sendermessage)

def t_sendmsg():
    s = threading.Thread(target=sendmsg)
    s.start()

at = 0

def sendmsg():
    global at
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as g:
        hostname = 'Lenovo-PC'
        port = 5986

        if at==0:
            g.connect((hostname, port))
            msg = messagebox.get()
            lstbox.insert(0, 'You: ' +msg)
            g.send(msg.encode())
            at += 1

        else:
            msg = messagebox.get()
            lstbox.insert(0, 'You: ' +msg)
            g.send(msg.encode())
```

And my client code is same with minor difference

```
import socket
import time
import threading
from tkinter import *

#functions
def t_recv():
    r = threading.Thread(target=recv)
    r.start()

def recv():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as listensocket:
        port = 5986
        maxconnections = 9
        ip = socket.gethostname()
        print(ip)
        FORMAT = 'utf-8'
        host = 'MY_IP'    # My actual ip is there in the code

        listensocket.bind((host, port))
        listensocket.listen(maxconnections)
        (clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()


        while True:
            sendermessage = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
            if not sendermessage == "":                 
                time.sleep(3)                 
                lstbox.insert(0, 'Server: ' +sendermessage)

def t_sendmsg():
    s = threading.Thread(target=sendmsg)
    s.start()

at = 0

def sendmsg():
    global at
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as g:
        hostname = 'Lenovo-PC'
        port = 5354

        if at==0:
            g.connect((hostname, port))
            msg = messagebox.get()
            lstbox.insert(0, 'You: ' +msg)
            g.send(msg.encode())
            at += 1

        else:
            msg = messagebox.get()
            lstbox.insert(0, 'You: ' +msg)
            g.send(msg.encode())
```

Please let me know what changes are required to be made in order to make it run for every message.

I tried to put

```
g.connect((hostname, port))
```

the above line in the loop so that it will connect every time loop iterates. But it did not help.

Comment: I recommend that you create a minimal reproducible example of your problem without the encumbrance of tkinter

Answer (score 0):

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as g:
    ...

    if at==0:
        g.connect((hostname, port))
        ...
        g.send(msg.encode())
        at += 1

    else:
        ...
        g.send(msg.encode())
```

In the `if at==0` condition it connects to the server, in the `else` part not. But is still trying to send something on the **not connected** socket.

Comment: even if I put 
```
g.connect((hostname, port))
```
Outside of if statement, the same thing happens.

Comment: @PyProgrammer: please reduce your code to the bare minimum needed to reproduce your problem - i.e. remove all the tkinter stuff and more. Then show what you exactly did (code) instead of only stating *"even if ... [do something] ... the same thing happens"*. Also provide the full stacktrace with line numbers matching your code to make sure that the error is  even triggered by the part of the code where you made the changes

Comment: @PyProgrammer: the problem of not calling connect is still there. There is still no stacktrace for the error. The code is also not complete so one can reproduce the problem.